# Using Windows Biometric Framework, or any other method to access the Fingerprint reader with .Net

Tags: c#, c++, .net, fingerprint, biometrics

I am looking to access a persons fingerprint and use it as the persons identifier.

I have looked at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee829699(v=vs.85).aspx , and the pages it leads to, but I cannot figure out the first step required everywhere, which is:

> link to the Winbio.lib static library

I cant even find this file on my machine

I tried the solution mentioned on : http://weblogs.asp.net/thomaslebrun/archive/2009/08/19/windows-seven-how-to-use-biometric-authentication-in-your-net-applications.aspx , and while it does work, it needs the fingerprint to be registered with Windows to work(not a major issue), and, more importantly, doesn't show me how it actually works and how the actual API's are being called

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will find Winbio.dll in your OS itself. The most probable path to this dll is

1. %windir%\system32\winbio.dll
2. %windir%\winsxs\backup\x86_microsoft-windows-s..
3. %windir%\winsxs\x86_microsoft-windows-s..y-biometrics-client_31bf3856ad364e35_6.‌​1.7000.0_none_2282a6cbc0bff05e\winbio.dll

Comment: Could you please give some sample code to let know how to get started on it? @Rahat Khanna